# Deploying Airbyte with just docker-compose.yaml and varibles

Tags: docker-compose, airbyte

I am working on a project with Airbyte. Is pretty easy the deployment with docker compose following the documentation. I just had to clone the repository and use docker compose up.

When I clone the repository a lot of files are downloaded. When I run docker compose up the images are downloaded too.

I did a test with a new directory containing just the docker-compose.yaml, .env and flags.yml files, required to start the containers. Everything worked fine!

What are the implications of running the containers with just these 3 files?

Thanks in advance!

I checked the number of connectors and functionality, both cases worked perfectly.

Comment: also curious, because i'm trying to use podman..but running into issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it setup by initially following the instructions located here: https://docs.airbyte.com/deploying-airbyte/local-deployment/

After running the `./run-ab-platform.sh` command it generates a `docker-compose.yaml`, `flags.yml` and an `.env` file that I copied over to a location with no internet access along with the images.

Here is the files it produced with version 0.50.4

### `.env` file

```
# This file only contains Docker relevant variables.
#
# Variables with defaults have been omitted to avoid duplication of defaults.
# The only exception to the non-default rule are env vars related to scaling.
#
# See https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte/blob/master/airbyte-config/config-models/src/main/java/io/airbyte/config/Configs.java
# for the latest environment variables.
#
# # Contributors - please organise this env file according to the above linked file.


### SHARED ###
VERSION=0.50.5

# When using the airbyte-db via default docker image
CONFIG_ROOT=/data
DATA_DOCKER_MOUNT=airbyte_data
DB_DOCKER_MOUNT=airbyte_db

# Workspace storage for running jobs (logs, etc)
WORKSPACE_ROOT=/tmp/workspace
WORKSPACE_DOCKER_MOUNT=airbyte_workspace

# Local mount to access local files from filesystem
# todo (cgardens) - when we are mount raw directories instead of named volumes, *_DOCKER_MOUNT must
# be the same as *_ROOT.
# Issue: https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte/issues/578
LOCAL_ROOT=/tmp/airbyte_local
LOCAL_DOCKER_MOUNT=/tmp/airbyte_local
# todo (cgardens) - hack to handle behavior change in docker compose. *_PARENT directories MUST
# already exist on the host filesystem and MUST be parents of *_ROOT.
# Issue: https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte/issues/577
HACK_LOCAL_ROOT_PARENT=/tmp

# Proxy Configuration
# Set to empty values, e.g. "" to disable basic auth
BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=airbyte
BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=password
BASIC_AUTH_PROXY_TIMEOUT=900

### DATABASE ###
# Airbyte Internal Job Database, see https://docs.airbyte.io/operator-guides/configuring-airbyte-db
DATABASE_USER=docker
DATABASE_PASSWORD=docker
DATABASE_HOST=db
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_DB=airbyte
# translate manually DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_DB} (do not include the username or password here)
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/airbyte
JOBS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION=0.40.26.001

# Airbyte Internal Config Database, defaults to Job Database if empty. Explicitly left empty to mute docker compose warnings.
CONFIG_DATABASE_USER=
CONFIG_DATABASE_PASSWORD=
CONFIG_DATABASE_URL=
CONFIGS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION=0.40.23.002

### AIRBYTE SERVICES ###
TEMPORAL_HOST=airbyte-temporal:7233
INTERNAL_API_HOST=airbyte-server:8001
CONNECTOR_BUILDER_API_HOST=airbyte-connector-builder-server:80
WEBAPP_URL=http://localhost:8000/
# Although not present as an env var, required for webapp configuration.
CONNECTOR_BUILDER_API_URL=/connector-builder-api

### JOBS ###
# Relevant to scaling.
SYNC_JOB_MAX_ATTEMPTS=3
SYNC_JOB_MAX_TIMEOUT_DAYS=3
SYNC_JOB_INIT_RETRY_TIMEOUT_MINUTES=5
JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_REQUEST=
JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_LIMIT=
JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_REQUEST=
JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT=

NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT=
NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_REQUEST=
NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_LIMIT=
NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_REQUEST=

### LOGGING/MONITORING/TRACKING ###
TRACKING_STRATEGY=segment
JOB_ERROR_REPORTING_STRATEGY=logging
# Although not present as an env var, expected by Log4J configuration.
LOG_LEVEL=INFO


### APPLICATIONS ###
# Worker #
WORKERS_MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=control-plane
# Cron #
CRON_MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=control-plane
# Relevant to scaling.
MAX_SYNC_WORKERS=5
MAX_SPEC_WORKERS=5
MAX_CHECK_WORKERS=5
MAX_DISCOVER_WORKERS=5
MAX_NOTIFY_WORKERS=5
SHOULD_RUN_NOTIFY_WORKFLOWS=true
# Temporal Activity configuration
ACTIVITY_MAX_ATTEMPT=
ACTIVITY_INITIAL_DELAY_BETWEEN_ATTEMPTS_SECONDS=
ACTIVITY_MAX_DELAY_BETWEEN_ATTEMPTS_SECONDS=
WORKFLOW_FAILURE_RESTART_DELAY_SECONDS=

### FEATURE FLAGS ###
AUTO_DISABLE_FAILING_CONNECTIONS=false

FEATURE_FLAG_CLIENT=config

### MONITORING FLAGS ###
# Accepted values are datadog and otel (open telemetry)
METRIC_CLIENT=
# Useful only when metric client is set to be otel. Must start with http:// or https://.
OTEL_COLLECTOR_ENDPOINT="http://host.docker.internal:4317"

USE_STREAM_CAPABLE_STATE=true
AUTO_DETECT_SCHEMA=true

# To test local catalog changes, set the below variable to the path of your local catalog.
# https://docs.airbyte.com/connector-development/testing-connectors/testing-a-local-catalog-in-development
LOCAL_CONNECTOR_CATALOG_PATH=
```

### `docker-compose.yaml` file

```yaml
version: "3.8"
#https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#using-extensions-as-fragments
x-logging: &default-logging
  options:
    max-size: "100m"
    max-file: "5"
  driver: json-file
services:
  # hook in case we need to add init behavior
  # every root service (no depends_on) should depend on init
  init:
    image: airbyte/init:${VERSION}
    logging: *default-logging
    container_name: init
    command: /bin/sh -c "./scripts/create_mount_directories.sh /local_parent ${HACK_LOCAL_ROOT_PARENT} ${LOCAL_ROOT}"
    environment:
      - LOCAL_ROOT=${LOCAL_ROOT}
      - HACK_LOCAL_ROOT_PARENT=${HACK_LOCAL_ROOT_PARENT}
    volumes:
      - ${HACK_LOCAL_ROOT_PARENT}:/local_parent
  bootloader:
    image: airbyte/bootloader:${VERSION}
    logging: *default-logging
    container_name: airbyte-bootloader
    environment:
      - AIRBYTE_VERSION=${VERSION}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - LOG_LEVEL=${LOG_LEVEL}
      - LOCAL_CONNECTOR_CATALOG_PATH=${LOCAL_CONNECTOR_CATALOG_PATH}
    networks:
      - airbyte_internal
    depends_on:
      init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  db:
    image: airbyte/db:${VERSION}
    logging: *default-logging
    container_name: airbyte-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - CONFIG_DATABASE_PASSWORD=${CONFIG_DATABASE_PASSWORD:-}
      - CONFIG_DATABASE_URL=${CONFIG_DATABASE_URL:-}
      - CONFIG_DATABASE_USER=${CONFIG_DATABASE_USER:-}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - airbyte_internal
  worker:
    image: airbyte/worker:${VERSION}
    logging: *default-logging
    container_name: airbyte-worker
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - AIRBYTE_VERSION=${VERSION}
      - AUTO_DISABLE_FAILING_CONNECTIONS=${AUTO_DISABLE_FAILING_CONNECTIONS}
      - CONFIG_DATABASE_PASSWORD=${CONFIG_DATABASE_PASSWORD:-}
      - CONFIG_DATABASE_URL=${CONFIG_DATABASE_URL:-}
      - CONFIG_DATABASE_USER=${CONFIG_DATABASE_USER:-}
      - CONFIGS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION=${CONFIGS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION:-}
      - CONFIG_ROOT=${CONFIG_ROOT}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - DEPLOYMENT_MODE=${DEPLOYMENT_MODE}
      - FEATURE_FLAG_CLIENT=${FEATURE_FLAG_CLIENT}
      - LAUNCHDARKLY_KEY=${LAUNCHDARKLY_KEY}
      - INTERNAL_API_HOST=${INTERNAL_API_HOST}
      - JOBS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION=${JOBS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION:-}
      - JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_LIMIT=${JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_LIMIT}
      - JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_REQUEST=${JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_REQUEST}
      - JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT=${JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT}
      - JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_REQUEST=${JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_REQUEST}
      - LOCAL_DOCKER_MOUNT=${LOCAL_DOCKER_MOUNT}
      - LOCAL_ROOT=${LOCAL_ROOT}
      - LOG_LEVEL=${LOG_LEVEL}
      - LOG_CONNECTOR_MESSAGES=${LOG_CONNECTOR_MESSAGES}
      - MAX_CHECK_WORKERS=${MAX_CHECK_WORKERS}
      - MAX_DISCOVER_WORKERS=${MAX_DISCOVER_WORKERS}
      - MAX_SPEC_WORKERS=${MAX_SPEC_WORKERS}
      - MAX_SYNC_WORKERS=${MAX_SYNC_WORKERS}
      - MAX_NOTIFY_WORKERS=${MAX_NOTIFY_WORKERS}
      - SHOULD_RUN_NOTIFY_WORKFLOWS=${SHOULD_RUN_NOTIFY_WORKFLOWS}
      - NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT=${NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT}
      - NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_REQUEST=${NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_REQUEST}
      - NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_LIMIT=${NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_LIMIT}
      - NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_REQUEST=${NORMALIZATION_JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_REQUEST}
      - SECRET_PERSISTENCE=${SECRET_PERSISTENCE}
      - SYNC_JOB_MAX_ATTEMPTS=${SYNC_JOB_MAX_ATTEMPTS}
      - SYNC_JOB_MAX_TIMEOUT_DAYS=${SYNC_JOB_MAX_TIMEOUT_DAYS}
      - SYNC_JOB_INIT_RETRY_TIMEOUT_MINUTES=${SYNC_JOB_INIT_RETRY_TIMEOUT_MINUTES}
      - TEMPORAL_HOST=${TEMPORAL_HOST}
      - TRACKING_STRATEGY=${TRACKING_STRATEGY}
      - WEBAPP_URL=${WEBAPP_URL}
      - WORKSPACE_DOCKER_MOUNT=${WORKSPACE_DOCKER_MOUNT}
      - WORKSPACE_ROOT=${WORKSPACE_ROOT}
      - METRIC_CLIENT=${METRIC_CLIENT}
      - OTEL_COLLECTOR_ENDPOINT=${OTEL_COLLECTOR_ENDPOINT}
      - JOB_ERROR_REPORTING_STRATEGY=${JOB_ERROR_REPORTING_STRATEGY}
      - JOB_ERROR_REPORTING_SENTRY_DSN=${JOB_ERROR_REPORTING_SENTRY_DSN}
      - ACTIVITY_MAX_ATTEMPT=${ACTIVITY_MAX_ATTEMPT}
      - ACTIVITY_INITIAL_DELAY_BETWEEN_ATTEMPTS_SECONDS=${ACTIVITY_INITIAL_DELAY_BETWEEN_ATTEMPTS_SECONDS}
      - ACTIVITY_MAX_DELAY_BETWEEN_ATTEMPTS_SECONDS=${ACTIVITY_MAX_DELAY_BETWEEN_ATTEMPTS_SECONDS}
      - WORKFLOW_FAILURE_RESTART_DELAY_SECONDS=${WORKFLOW_FAILURE_RESTART_DELAY_SECONDS}
      - AUTO_DETECT_SCHEMA=${AUTO_DETECT_SCHEMA}
      - USE_STREAM_CAPABLE_STATE=${USE_STREAM_CAPABLE_STATE}
      - MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=${WORKERS_MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS}
      - APPLY_FIELD_SELECTION=${APPLY_FIELD_SELECTION}
      - FIELD_SELECTION_WORKSPACES=${FIELD_SELECTION_WORKSPACES}
    configs:
      - flags
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - workspace:${WORKSPACE_ROOT}
      - ${LOCAL_ROOT}:${LOCAL_ROOT}
    ports:
      - "9000"
    networks:
      - airbyte_internal
    depends_on:
      bootloader:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  server:
    image: airbyte/server:${VERSION}
    logging: *default-logging
    container_name: airbyte-server
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - AIRBYTE_ROLE=${AIRBYTE_ROLE:-}
      - AIRBYTE_VERSION=${VERSION}
      - CONFIG_DATABASE_PASSWORD=${CONFIG_DATABASE_PASSWORD:-}
      - CONFIG_DATABASE_URL=${CONFIG_DATABASE_URL:-}
      - CONFIG_DATABASE_USER=${CONFIG_DATABASE_USER:-}
      - CONFIGS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION=${CONFIGS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION:-}
      - CONFIG_ROOT=${CONFIG_ROOT}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - FEATURE_FLAG_CLIENT=${FEATURE_FLAG_CLIENT}
      - LAUNCHDARKLY_KEY=${LAUNCHDARKLY_KEY}
      - JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_LIMIT=${JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_LIMIT}
      - JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_REQUEST=${JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_CPU_REQUEST}
      - JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT=${JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT}
      - JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_REQUEST=${JOB_MAIN_CONTAINER_MEMORY_REQUEST}
      - JOBS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION=${JOBS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION:-}
      - LOG_LEVEL=${LOG_LEVEL}
      - NEW_SCHEDULER=${NEW_SCHEDULER}
      - SECRET_PERSISTENCE=${SECRET_PERSISTENCE}
      - TEMPORAL_HOST=${TEMPORAL_HOST}
      - TRACKING_STRATEGY=${TRACKING_STRATEGY}
      - JOB_ERROR_REPORTING_STRATEGY=${JOB_ERROR_REPORTING_STRATEGY}
      - JOB_ERROR_REPORTING_SENTRY_DSN=${JOB_ERROR_REPORTING_SENTRY_DSN}
      - WEBAPP_URL=${WEBAPP_URL}
      - WORKER_ENVIRONMENT=${WORKER_ENVIRONMENT}
      - WORKSPACE_ROOT=${WORKSPACE_ROOT}
      - GITHUB_STORE_BRANCH=${GITHUB_STORE_BRANCH}
      - MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=${WORKERS_MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS}
      - AUTO_DETECT_SCHEMA=${AUTO_DETECT_SCHEMA}
      - MAX_NOTIFY_WORKERS=5
      - SHOULD_RUN_NOTIFY_WORKFLOWS=${SHOULD_RUN_NOTIFY_WORKFLOWS}
    ports:
      - "8001"
    configs:
      - flags
    volumes:
      - workspace:${WORKSPACE_ROOT}
      - data:${CONFIG_ROOT}
      - ${LOCAL_ROOT}:${LOCAL_ROOT}
    networks:
      - airbyte_internal
    depends_on:
      bootloader:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  webapp:
    image: airbyte/webapp:${VERSION}
    logging: *default-logging
    container_name: airbyte-webapp
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - INTERNAL_API_HOST=${INTERNAL_API_HOST}
      - CONNECTOR_BUILDER_API_HOST=${CONNECTOR_BUILDER_API_HOST}
      - TRACKING_STRATEGY=${TRACKING_STRATEGY}
    networks:
      - airbyte_internal
    depends_on:
      bootloader:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  airbyte-temporal:
    image: airbyte/temporal:${VERSION}
    logging: *default-logging
    container_name: airbyte-temporal
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - DB=postgresql
      - DB_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
      - DYNAMIC_CONFIG_FILE_PATH=config/dynamicconfig/development.yaml
      - LOG_LEVEL=${LOG_LEVEL}
      - POSTGRES_PWD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_SEEDS=${DATABASE_HOST}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
    volumes:
      - ./temporal/dynamicconfig:/etc/temporal/config/dynamicconfig
    networks:
      - airbyte_internal
  airbyte-cron:
    image: airbyte/cron:${VERSION}
    logging: *default-logging
    container_name: airbyte-cron
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - AIRBYTE_VERSION=${VERSION}
      - CONFIGS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION=${CONFIGS_DATABASE_MINIMUM_FLYWAY_MIGRATION_VERSION}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - DEPLOYMENT_MODE=${DEPLOYMENT_MODE}
      - LOG_LEVEL=${LOG_LEVEL}
      - REMOTE_CONNECTOR_CATALOG_URL=${REMOTE_CONNECTOR_CATALOG_URL}
      - TEMPORAL_HISTORY_RETENTION_IN_DAYS=${TEMPORAL_HISTORY_RETENTION_IN_DAYS}
      - UPDATE_DEFINITIONS_CRON_ENABLED=${UPDATE_DEFINITIONS_CRON_ENABLED}
      - WORKSPACE_ROOT=${WORKSPACE_ROOT}
      - MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=${CRON_MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS}
    configs:
      - flags
    volumes:
      - workspace:${WORKSPACE_ROOT}
    networks:
      - airbyte_internal
    depends_on:
      bootloader:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  airbyte-connector-builder-server:
    image: airbyte/connector-atelier-server:${VERSION}
    logging: *default-logging
    container_name: airbyte-connector-builder-server
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80
    environment:
      - AIRBYTE_VERSION=${VERSION}
      - CDK_VERSION=${CDK_VERSION}
      - DEPLOYMENT_MODE=${DEPLOYMENT_MODE}
      - PYTHON_VERSION=${PYTHON_VERSION}
    networks:
      - airbyte_internal
    depends_on:
      bootloader:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
  airbyte-proxy:
    image: airbyte/proxy:${VERSION}
    container_name: airbyte-proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8001:8001"
      - "8003:8003"
    environment:
      - BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=${BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME}
      - BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=${BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD}
      - BASIC_AUTH_PROXY_TIMEOUT=${BASIC_AUTH_PROXY_TIMEOUT}
    networks:
      - airbyte_internal
      - airbyte_public
    depends_on:
      - webapp
      - server
volumes:
  workspace:
    name: ${WORKSPACE_DOCKER_MOUNT}
  # the data volume is only needed for backward compatibility; when users upgrade
  # from an old Airbyte version that relies on file-based configs, the server needs
  # to read this volume to copy their configs to the database
  data:
    name: ${DATA_DOCKER_MOUNT}
  db:
    name: ${DB_DOCKER_MOUNT}
configs:
  flags:
    file: ./flags.yml
networks:
  airbyte_public:
  airbyte_internal:
```

### `flags.yml`

```yaml
flags:
  - name: performance.backgroundJsonSchemaValidation
    serve: false
  - name: heartbeat.failSync
    serve: true
  - name: platform.commitStatsAsap
    serve: true
  - name: connectors.versionOverridesEnabled
    serve: true
  - name: billing.newTrialPolicy
    serve: false
  - name: heartbeat-max-seconds-between-messages
    serve: "10800"
  - name: use-new-notification-workflow
    serve: false
  - name: validation.removeValidationLimit
    serve: false
  - name: autopropagation.enabled
    serve: true
  - name: connection.columnSelection
    serve: true
  - name: refreshSchema.period.hours
    serve: 24
  - name: concurrent.source.stream.read
    serve: false
  - name: platform.add-scheduling-jitter
    serve: false
```

Comment: This Means the airbyte team can work on a docker compose native implementation. Without the need to download a repository containing 2M+ objects and about 2gb+ worth of files for a local dev environment. @Marc Keeling are there any of these env vars or configs that use some configs from your local env hence a need to run the ` /run-ab-platform.sh` locally first ?